# Performance issue on two different instances within the same database

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-package

We are running into a performance issue while writing query data to a file from two different instance on same database.

ON DB1 with Instance A with some directory path data writing to file is taking 2-3 min, and Instance B with different directory path writing to file is taking ~90 min.

Explain plan for query on both instances are same.  Also, query execution time is the same on both instances.

Please let me know if there is an issue with the different directory path.

Comment: When you say two different instances of the same database, you mean two instances in a real application cluster (RAC)?  Or you mean two copies of the same database (like PROD and DEV)?

Comment: Not enough information for a definitive answer, but from the fact that you say "different directory path" I would guess this has far more to do with it than the database, some options that could be causing this 1) One directory could be local and the other network 2) one directory could point to a SSD and the other to a spinning disk.... The list goes on.  I would be discussing with the person who administers the server and finding out what is different between the two directory paths.

Comment: Thank you for your respond I am working with my DBA to look into the both directory access. but apart form this is there is any other suggestion or the area to focus on